# Error: Attempted to handle event 'becameInvalid' while in state root.loaded.created.invalid

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to make a form field validation system. When the focus-out event is triggered by the component, it adds a fake error. [Here's my jsbin.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tapeva/edit?html,js,output)

If you type something on the textarea and then focus out, it will add the "fake error" as expected. However if you do it again, it will raise the following error:

```js
Error: Attempted to handle event 'becameInvalid' on <App.Book:ember418:null> while in state root.loaded.created.invalid.
```

I notice It worked well until I switched ember-data from `1.13.6`. to `1.13.7`. So if you want to see the JSBIN working without error, switch ember-data to 1.13.6.

I would like to know if I'm doing something wrong.
Thanks for helping!

Comment: Im running into the same issue. Just wanted to let you know I opened an issue under Ember Data [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3707). Feel free to add to it!